# Eclipse Theme Issue

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, themes, customization

The Eclipse theme only seams to apply on the editor’s window and set area like ***Project Browser , Outline, Task windows etc seems unchanged.*** I have downloaded the themes form the Eclipse Market place but it has no effect. Is that the way it suppose to work or something is wrong with my Eclipse on installation.

I have manage to change the Java doc and Declaration Windows manually form the 
Windows ->Presences -> Color and Fonts

Plus I have tried putting pref files in the workspace as suggested by Eric in his blog :-

http://blog.edwards-research.com/2009/10/color-schemes-for-eclipse-cdt/
and Theme generator
"blog.edwards-research.com/files/eclipse-gen/#"

My present Eclipse looks like :- http://www.flickr.com/photos/deamonm/7101439563/

I wonder how did Aptana studio manage to change in the Eclipse plugin

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to change those part of eclipse except the editor window. You can download lots of theme from [Eclipse Theme](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/). Also note that there is a plug-in available,[here](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-color-theme) . It comes preloaded with many themes. After installing, Go to **Window->preference->search for theme and choose from variety of themes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Aptana plugin for Eclipse to change almost all the panels' view:

1. Follow the link [[Download Aptana Studio]](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download), choose "Eclipse Plug-in Version", then click on Download button. You'll be redirected to Installation page. Follow that installation guide.
2. In Eclipse menu select Preferences > Aptana Studio > Themes
3. Choose any theme that fits you the best (this will change editor view only).
4. Click on 3 check boxes below: Apply to all (non-Studio) views, Apply to all (non-Studio) editors, Apply editor font to views.
5. Click Apply or OK button.

And voila! Theme is applied globally.

UPDATE.

Unfortunately, this solutions doesn't work for ALL the panels. Some Perspectives cannot be modified by those actions.

Answer (score 0):

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-moonrise-ui-theme
go to this link
and follow instructions carefully!
*****Install the plugin;
Restart Eclipse and go to **Window > Preferences > General > Appearance**;
Select MoonRise (standalone) or, for a little better tabs decoration, install Eclipse 4 Chrome Theme from marketplace or from here and select MoonRise;*****
this must change your Project Browser , Outline, Task windows etc.
cheers!